# Why `previous`, not `next` variable has to be weak in DoublyLinkedList?

Tags: linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I spent a time to figure out why my doubly linked list function `append()` doesn't work. The reason was that I made as weak `next` instead of `previous`. But I can not find why it does matter. I thought ownership cycle it's just a cycle with "equal" instances.

I've read about reference counting, but can not find an answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although previous and next have completely symmetric roles, there is one important difference if your list has a *head* reference (to the first node in the list) and not a *tail* reference (to the last node in the list). In that scenario the symmetry is broken, and then it becomes important you make the right choice in terms of weak references.

Nodes in the list are then reachable through the *head* reference and then a chain of zero or more *next* references. If however these *next* references are weak references, nodes risk to be garbage collected. It doesn't help that they are referenced by strong *previous* references, since the "root" of that chain is the tail node of the list, which has no strong reference to it.